# How to make POST request via fetch API with local client and server?

Tags: javascript, webpack, fetch, webpack-dev-server

I am running two separate servers via webpack and express; dev server and client server.

I have a button on client and I want to send POST request to server on button click. I am creating request by using example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
const testButton = document.querySelector(`button.test`);

const sendRequest = event => {
    event.preventDefault(); //stop or prevents the browser from executing the default action

    postData(`http://localhost:8080/`, { answer: 42 }) // line:32
        .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) // JSON-string from `response.json()` call , line:33
        .catch(error => console.error(error));

    function postData(url = ``, data = {}) {
        // Default options are marked with *
        return fetch(url, { // line:38
            method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
            cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
            referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
            body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        });
        // .then(response => response.json()); // parses JSON response into native Javascript objects
    }

    console.log(`sends POST request from here`);
};
testButton.addEventListener(`click`, sendRequest);
```

When I click on the button, I get this error:

```
sends POST request from here // console.log message in request
POST http://localhost:8080/ 404 (Not Found)
postData @ index.js:38
sendRequest @ index.js:32
index.js:33 {}
```

scripts in package.json

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack",
        "dev-server": "nodemon bin/dev localhost 8080",
        "dev-client": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000"
    }
```

devServer in webpack.config.js

```
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,

        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
         proxy: {
          '/api/': 'http://localhost:8080',
          }
    },
```

I have tried this for proxy

```
proxy: {
          '^/api/*': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080/api/',
            secure: false
          }
        }
```

Comment: In your line 32, the used URL to POST your request is is http://localhost:8080/, but as if your devServer URL would be http://localhost:8080/api/, right?

Comment: yes. I realized as I typed in first. Then I changed webpack.config.js to `proxy: {
          '/api/': 'http://localhost:8080',
          }` and edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you start your express server?
2. Does your express app have empty endpoint mapping (it also must be POST mapping)?
3. And if you are using docker (for express), does it listen to your internal port?

Your request code looks fine at first glance.

Comment: My express app did not have empty endpoint mapping (it also must be POST mapping) `app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('POST request to the homepage')
  })` fixed the issue.